# PlayFramework - what is the alternative to response.getBodyAsStream()?

Tags: playframework-2.0

The language says that  "response.getBodyAsStream()" is deprecated. Neat, what method do i use?

`* @deprecated use {@link #getBody(BodyReadable)} with {@code WSBodyWritables.inputStream()}.`

Oh...

That's not... english? Or anything, really. So. Do any of you clever stackoverflowers know how the hell I am *meant* to do the getBodyAsStream?

Answer (score 1):

From the source code this should work in java.

```
response.getBody(WSBodyReadables.instance.inputStream());
```